# Do I have to use $watch to dynamically pass isolate scope attributes to my custom controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a controller that stores super heroes. I would like to use a custom directive to display a certain super hero based on the value entered in an input field. I do not wish to achieve this with a filter. I am currently stuck, I am wondering if I need to implement something like $watch to do this? I would really like to do this with angular best practices. Thanks in advance!

**heroController.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('heroController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.superHero = [
    {firstName: 'superman', image: 'img/url.com', superPower: 'invisibility'},
    {firstName: 'batman', image: 'img/url.com', superPower: 'xray'},
    {firstName: 'stretch', image: 'img/url.com', superPower: 'flight'},
    {firstName: 'speedy', image: 'img/url.com', superPower: 'strength'},
    {firstName: 'aquaman', image: 'img/url.com', superPower: 'aqua'},
    {firstName: 'hulk', image: 'img/url.com', superPower: 'stretch'}
    ];

}]);
```

**heroDirective.js**

```
myApp.directive('heroDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: 'heroView.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            firstName: '@fname',
            lastName: '@lname',
            superPower: '@spower'
        }


    };
});
```

**heroView.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <figure>
        <ul>
            <li>{{superHero.firstName}}</li>
            <li>{{superHero.lastName}}</li>
            <li>{{superHero.image}}</li>
            <li>{{superHero.superPower}}</li>
        </ul>


    </figure>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet"      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<body ng-app="myApp">



<div ng-controller="heroController">
    <input ng-model="heroDirective.firstName"/>
    <hero-directive ></hero-directive>

</div>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
<script src="heroController.js"></script>
<script src="heroDirective.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a good case for a `filter` but since you requested not to use it, this is how i would implement it in angular:

#### http://plnkr.co/edit/rsStQ5lKdG9Qvm6X4Udz?p=preview

**.html**

```
<span>insert hero:</span>
<input ng-model="superHeroInput" />
<hero-directive super-hero="selectedSuperHero"></hero-directive>
```

**.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('heroController', function($scope, $location, $timeout) {

  $scope.superHeros = [{
    firstName: 'superman',
    image: 'img/url.com',
    superPower: 'invisibility'
  }, {
    firstName: 'batman',
    image: 'img/url.com',
    superPower: 'xray'
  }, {
    firstName: 'stretch',
    image: 'img/url.com',
    superPower: 'flight'
  }, {
    firstName: 'speedy',
    image: 'img/url.com',
    superPower: 'strength'
  }, {
    firstName: 'aquaman',
    image: 'img/url.com',
    superPower: 'aqua'
  }, {
    firstName: 'hulk',
    image: 'img/url.com',
    superPower: 'stretch'
  }];


  $scope.superHeroInput = '';

  $scope.$watch('superHeroInput', function(newValue) {
    if (!newValue || newValue.length == 0) {
      $scope.selectedSuperHero = $scope.superHeros[0];
    } else {
      var randomItem = $scope.superHeros[Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.superHeros.length)];
      $scope.selectedSuperHero = randomItem;
    }
  });
});

app.directive('heroDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    templateUrl: 'heroView.html',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      superHero: '='
    }
  };
});
```

**heroView.html**

```
<figure>
  <ul>
    <li>{{superHero.firstName}}</li>
    <li>{{superHero.image}}</li>
    <li>{{superHero.superPower}}</li>
  </ul>
</figure>
```

---

so what's happening?
the input text bounded to `superHeroInput`. when it changes, `$scope.$watch('superHeroInput', ...` is invoked with the new input and then if there is empty string i picked the first superhero, otherwise, random superhero **(you should place your superhero filtering logic there)**

after that there is a binding between the selected superhero and the directive. when the selected superhero is changed, the directive updates his view

Comment: I used a switch statement in the logic of the $watch function and it worked beautifully. Thanks for the help Jossef!